# Canvas flickers if size is over 256px on Android (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, canvas

I'm developing a coloring mobile app using Cordova and the project https://github.com/theisensanders-wf/responsive-sketchpad

Everything works fine, but the canvas flickers if is not exactly 256px or less. I made some tests changing on the console the size with the Sketchpad.resize() function, and always over 256px the canvas starts flickering. I inserted it without modifications, on a document.ready listener as follows:

```
window.pad = new Sketchpad(document.getElementById('canvasDiv'));
```

By flicker I meant the lines seems to have an effect of being blurry and then rendered again, and that behavior repeats every 1 second.

I tried using requestAnimationFrame but that made the performance very poor in terms of refresh rate. It is a coloring app so it is important that the feeling of drawing feels real time.

Comment: Tablet Android 7.1.1 Chrome 62 I don't see any flickering. In code I can see no obvious reason for flickering, but unsure what you mean by flickering (background flickering, lines flickering, or something else). I do not see you using `requestAnimationFrame` which will eliminate many causes of flickering. Also you redraw all drawn content for each UI event, which will chew power and UI sample rate drops quickly. Suggest you store previous lines on a second canvas and only render current line, this will reduce load and may also reduce flickering. But without more info on what flicker means...

Comment: ... there is not much more I can suggest.

Comment: @Blindman67 I updated the question. I do not see flickering on the demo site of the plugin. However, it is happening on Cordova. I'll try to create a blank cordova project and put it here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it still works but there's [a plugin to improve canvas speed on android](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas).

The only thing is that it hasn't been maintained for 4 years now...